# Testing Text To Speech (TTS) in browser

Tags: twilio

There is a really old blog entry from Twilio about testing the TTS in browser:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2011/08/testing-twilios-text-to-speech-engine-using-twilio-client.html

Unfortunately it doesn't contain enough information to put a test together. It also contains a number of dead links and mentions a Github project that I can't find.

I'd really like for users to have the ability to hear what their announcement will sound like prior to firing off the form and starting the phone calls.

I use Lasso (which fires off CURL requests to the Twilio REST API), but any kind of tutorials or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see updated answer that references Twilio in it's latest version.   The code provided in the blog is from an old version of Twilio however with modification of the code an use of non-deprecated client code I was able to get it to work.

Comment: Check out the text to speech tester in your Twilio console here: https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/twiml/text-to-speech

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a demo account on Twilio and use Glitch online php tester (https://glitch.com/edit/#!/php-poc) or a local environment you can create a workable example like I did.  You will need to fill in the empty strings to correspond to your app name.  Search for TwiML in the website to get to the right section to set the right url of your server that TWilio will call upon request to read content (xml).  In my case url was  `http://<server>/?incoming-call.php`   tested on Glitch.

You need to grab the Twilio PHP SDK and include the `Services/Twilio/Capability.php` from https://github.com/twilio/starter-php in your server code.

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
$url = [];
$url = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (count($url) == 2 && $url[1] == 'incoming-call.php')
  {
       header('Content-type: text/xml');
       $response = new Twilio\Twiml;
       $dialogue = trim($_REQUEST['dialogue']);  
       $voice = (int) $_REQUEST['voice'];  

       if (strlen($dialogue) == 0)
       {  
              $dialogue = 'Please enter some text to be spoken.';  
       } 
       if ($voice == 1)
       {  
             $gender = 'man'; 
       }
       else
       {  
             $gender = 'woman'; 
       } 
       $response->say($dialogue);
       echo $response;
       exit;
  }
  require_once('Services/Twilio/Capability.php');

  $accountsid = '';  //  YOUR TWILIO ACCOUNT SID
  $authtoken = '';   //  YOUR TWILIO AUTH TOKEN
  $fromNumber = '';  //  PHONE NUMBER CALLS WILL COME FROM

  $APP_SID = '';
  $token = new Services_Twilio_Capability($accountsid, $authtoken);
  $token->allowClientOutgoing($APP_SID);
?>
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>Text-To-Speech</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src= 
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.5/twilio.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    Twilio.Device.setup("<?php echo $token->generateToken();?>",{"debug":true});
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#submit").click(function() {
        speak();
      });
    });
    function speak() {
      var dialogue = $("#dialogue").val();
      var voice = 
        $('input:radio[name=voice]:checked').val();
       Twilio.Device.connect({ 'dialogue' : 
        dialogue, 'voice' : voice });
    }
  </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<p> 
  <label for="dialogue">Text to be spoken</label> 
  <input type="text" id="dialogue" name="dialogue" 
    size="50">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="voice-male">Male Voice</label>
  <input type="radio" id="voice-male" name="voice" 
    value="1" checked="checked"> 
  <label for="voice-female">Female Voice</label> 
  <input type="radio" id="voice-female" name="voice" 
    value="2">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" 
    value="Speak to me"> 
</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```